# What is PATH on a Mac (UNIX) system?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, path

I'm trying to setup a project, storm from git:
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Setting-up-development-environment

> Download a Storm release , unpack it, and put the unpacked bin/ directory on your PATH

My question is: What does PATH mean? What exactly do they want me to do?

Sometimes I see some /bin/path, $PATH, or echo PATH.

Can someone explain the concept of PATH, so I can setup everything easily in the future without just blindly following the instructions?

Comment: Regarding the votes for closure, I can think of two reasons this may be happening: (1) this is arguably not a *programming* question, per se, and thus may not fit [the on-topic standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and instead belong on, say, [SU](http://superuser.com/), and/or (2) that it's a question likely asked (and answered) before.  It strikes me as a valid enough question to have, though (even if this may be the wrong place to post it), so I've added an answer, that I hope you'll find helpful.  Best!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

PATH is a special environment variable in UNIX (and UNIX-like, e.g. GNU/Linux) systems, which is frequently used and manipulated by the shell (though other things can use it, as well).

There's a somewhat terse explanation [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), but basically it's used to define where to search for executable files (whether binaries, shell scripts, whatever).

You can find out what your current PATH is set to with a simple shell command:

```
: $; echo $PATH
```

(Note: the `: $;` is meant to represent your shell prompt; it may be something very different for you; just know that whatever your prompt is, that's what I'm representing with that string.)

Depending on your system and prior configuration, the value will vary, but a very simple example of the output might be something like:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

This is a colon(`:`)-separated list of directories in which to search for executable files (things like `ls`, et cetera.)  In short, when you try to execute a command from your shell (or from within some other program in certain ways), it will search through each of the directories in this list, in order, looking for an executable file of the name you're provided, and run the first one it finds.  So that's the concept, per your question.

From there, what this documentation is telling you to do is to add the directory where you've unpacked the software, and in particular its `bin` subdirectory, into your `$PATH` variable.  How to do this depends a bit on which shell you're using, but for most ([Bourne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)-compatible) shells, you should be able to do something like this, if you're in the directory where that `bin` directory is:

```
: $; PATH="$PATH:$PWD/bin"; export PATH
```

In just about all but an actual Bourne shell, this can be shortened to:

```
: $; export PATH="$PATH:$PWD/bin"
```

(I won't bother explaining for CSH-compatible shells (because: I agree with other advice that you [don't use them](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)), but something similar can be done in them, as well, if that happens to be your environment of choice for some reason.)

Presumably, though, you'll want to save this to a shell-specific configuration file (could be `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`... depending on your shell), and without reference to `$PWD`, but rather to whatever it expanded to.  One way you might accomplish this would be to do something like this:

```
: $; echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:$PWD/bin\""
```

and then copy/paste the resulting line into the appropriate configuration file.

Of course you could also generate the appropriate command in other ways, especially if your `$PWD` isn't currently where that `bin` directory is.

See also:

- [An article about `$PATH`](http://scientificocean.com/2013/02/17/an-introduction-to-linuxunix-executables-path-aliases-and-symlinks/) (and more)
- [a related question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/238987/how-does-unix-search-for-executable-files)

Comment: Unfortunately the first link is broken.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention.  I found an updated link to the same content, and have updated it in the answer.  (Note: It was the first See also link, not the first link in the answer overall.)