# unable to run grunt after installing using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to install and use grunt.

I install using npm install grunt -g

it seems to install -

```
grunt@0.4.3 /Users/me/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt
```

when I open up a new tab in terminal and run grunt I get

```
 -bash: grunt: command not found
```

My path looks like this

```
$ echo $PATH
            /Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Any advice? This is killing me.

---

I've installed grunt-cli too, still not working -

```
 npm install grunt-cli -g

/Users/me/.node/bin/grunt -> /Users/me/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
```

I open a new tab

```
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

---

I installed node using the node installer. I'm on OSX.

I've just added /.node/bin to my path, see below  -

```
 echo $PATH
 /Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/.node/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/.node/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

It's still not working.

Comment: You have to install `grunt-cli` to run from command line :)

Comment: have done, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path don't contain ~/.node/bin where apparently your globally installed npm binaries are kept.

You need to fix that if you expect said binaries to be picked-up.

Either way, this points out that you missed a step in your node / npm installation. How did you installed node exactly?

I don't know what other people do, but I'm using node from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), which should take care of that for you (I assume from the paths you list that you are on OSX).

Comment: thanks for looking at this, still not working. Added some info to my answer.

Comment: What you added to your path is *wrong*. /.node/bin is not the same thing as ~/.node/bin - to clear the confusion: add /Users/me/.node/bin to your path.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks v much. You have no idea how much this was frustrating me. I owe you a drink.

Comment: Happy it helped! I'm in for the drink :-) (@MangledDeutz)

Comment: I'm leaving this here as a reference to anyone who may need it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409707/what-is-path-on-the-mac-unix-system

Answer (score 0):

try to install grunt globally

```
   $ sudo npm install grunt -G
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have `Grunt 0.4.3` installed globally but nothing installed locally.

1. Run `$ grunt --version` to find which version you are on. At this point you'll only be knowing that you do have `Grunt` installed in your system. But to run `Grunt` at the directory level (also known as "project level") you'll need to be specific - because not every project may require the `Grunt` version you have installed globally.
2. Create a `package.json` file in the directory you mean to have your project on. Let's call it the project's root folder.

   ```
   {
       "name" : "MyProject",
       "version" : "0.1.0",
       "author" : "My name",
       "private" : true,

       "devDependencies" : {
           "grunt" : "~0.4.2"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Navigate to the project's root folder and run `$ npm install`. The specified `Grunt` version will be installed as a dependency to the project.
4. Smile, you have `Grunt` up and running! :)

Comment: It will of course help to have a few more dependencies and setup a `Gruntfile.js` to see stuff happening, but the above is enough to get started.

Comment: When I try to run grunt --version I get -bash: grunt: command not found

Comment: Right. Did you try installing `Grunt` globally with `sudo`? Did you try skipping to step 2 and further?

Comment: This is really good, and it will be even better if you add 1. log in as root. 2. ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node for those who have errors such as "/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes another version or just a wrong path is referenced in the npm config file instead of the installed version.

This may cause node/npm to misplace global modules.

To check and fix:

1. In cmd line type: `npm config list`
   You should get a list of configuration values, one of them is `prefix`.
2. Make sure the path in `prefix` is the same path (only without node.exe) as the actually installed node.exe path.
   (this path is listed further down as `node bin location`)
3. If it's not, change it:

   - Either in the config file (in your user folder, named .npmrc)
   - Or, via cmd line: `npm config set prefix "C:\Program Files\nodejs"` (change path if needed)
4. Reinstall the module/package you tried to install, don't forget -g for global.