# PHP version on MacOS X 10.11 issue

Tags: php

Recently I updated the default PHP version on MacOS X 10.11 to the newer 7.1.4, but when I do php -v on the terminal it says this: PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2016 21:48:49).

I created the phpinfo on the web root and it says that the version is actually the 7.1.4.

What should I do to resolve this issue? Is this a real issue?

Comment: "Recently I updated the default PHP version on MacOS X 10.11 to the newer 7.1.4," — How?

Comment: "when I do php -v on terminal it says this: PHP 5.5.38" — So you didn't update the command line version of PHP

Comment: "I created the phpinfo on the web root and it says that the version is actually the 7.1.4" — but you did upgrade the Apache module

Comment: "Is this a really issue?" — Is it causing you problems?

Comment: @Quentin I used the command curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1

Comment: "So you didn't update the command line version of PHP" how am I supposed to do that? I'm not a experienced OS X user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is PATH on the MAC (UNIX) system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18409707/1255289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said:

> I used the command `curl -s php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1`

I took a look at https://php-osx.liip.ch, which says:

> ## Why does php -v on the command line still show my old version?
>
> php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but
>   installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is
>   therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.
>
> You can also adjust your PATH do include that directory, eg. write
>   into your ~/.profile file the following
>
> ```
> export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
> ```